# Automatically refactor python lambdas to named functions

Tags: python

I am working on the [purescript-python](https://github.com/purescript-python) project and there are several core libraries that make extensive use of lambdas. Because of the way the code is compiled, the location of the lambdas winds up getting obscured, which results in bizarre console messages whenever an error occurs.

I would like to refactor these libraries to use lambdas as little as possible. So, for example, if there is something like:

```py
def foo(a):
  return lambda b: lambda c: lambda d: lambda e: a + b + c + d + e
```

it would be nice to generate

```py
def foo(a):
  def _foo_internal_anon_1(b):
    def _foo_internal_anon_2(c):
        def _foo_internal_anon_3(d):
          def _foo_internal_anon_4(e):
            return a + b + c + d + e
          return _foo_internal_anon_4
        return _foo_internal_anon_3
    return _foo_internal_anon_2
  return _foo_internal_anon_1
```

Is there a way to do this, ie with `pylint` or a vscode or pycharm plugin, or does this have to be done by hand?

Comment: The point of ``lambda`` is that it can occur at places where ``def`` is not valid. What are your requirements to convert a ``lambda`` to a ``def``?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a custom [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) to transform `Lambda` inside `Return` nodes to full function definitions. The transformed AST can then be unparsed with help of the [`unparse.py` tool](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Tools/parser/unparse.py) from the CPython repo (starting with Python 3.9 you can also use [`ast.unparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse)). This allows to transform a whole script, not just single functions.

This is the node transformer:

```py
import ast
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def resetattr(obj, name, value):
    old_value = getattr(obj, name)
    setattr(obj, name, value)
    yield
    setattr(obj, name, old_value)


class ConvertLambda(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_name = None
        self.n = 0

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.body[-1], ast.Return) and isinstance(node.body[-1].value, ast.Lambda):
            lambda_node = node.body[-1].value
            with resetattr(self, 'base_name', self.base_name or node.name):
                with resetattr(self, 'n', self.n+1):
                    func_name = f'_{self.base_name}_internal_anon_{self.n}'
                    func_def = ast.FunctionDef(
                        name=func_name,
                        args=lambda_node.args,
                        body=[ast.Return(value=lambda_node.body)],
                        decorator_list=[],
                        returns=None,
                    )
                    self.visit(func_def)
            node.body.insert(-1, func_def)
            node.body[-1].value = ast.Name(id=func_name)
        return node
```

It can be used together with the [`Unparser` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Tools/parser/unparse.py#L25) as follows (or alternatively [`ast.unparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) for Python 3.9+):

```py
from unparse import Unparser

def convert_func_def(text):
    tree = ast.parse(text)
    tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(ConvertLambda().visit(tree))
    Unparser(tree)
```

By default this prints the result to `sys.stdout` but `Unparser` can be configured to use any file-like object: `Unparser(tree, file=...)`.

This is the result obtained for the example function:

```py
def foo(a):

    def _foo_internal_anon_1(b):

        def _foo_internal_anon_2(c):

            def _foo_internal_anon_3(d):

                def _foo_internal_anon_4(e):
                    return ((((a + b) + c) + d) + e)
                return _foo_internal_anon_4
            return _foo_internal_anon_3
        return _foo_internal_anon_2
    return _foo_internal_anon_1
```

It adds some additional blank lines and parentheses around the addition but this can also be customized by modifying the `Unparser` class.

Answer (score -1):

Not completely automatic but you could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the various `lambda` inside a function. Perhaps you can turn that into a macro for your favorite IDE which allows you to highlight some text and then run the transformation on it.

```py
import functools
import re
import textwrap

def convert_func_def(text):
    """Assumes a multiple of 4 spaces as indentation."""
    func_name = re.search('def (.+?)(?=[(])', text).group(1)
    n_lambda = text.count('lambda')
    for i in range(n_lambda):
        text = re.sub(
            '^( +)return lambda (.+?): (.+?)$',
            functools.partial(replace, func_name=f'_{func_name}_internal_anon_{i+1}'),
            text,
            count=1,
            flags=re.MULTILINE,
        )
    return text

def replace(match, *, func_name):
    indent, args, body = match.groups()
    template = textwrap.dedent(f'''
        def {func_name}({args}):
            return {body}
        return {func_name}
    ''').strip()
    return textwrap.indent(template, indent)
```

Applied to your example function:

```py
print(convert_func_def('''def foo(a):
    return lambda b: lambda c: lambda d: lambda e: a + b + c + d + e'''))
```

this is the output:

```py
def foo(a):
    def _foo_internal_anon_1(b):
        def _foo_internal_anon_2(c):
            def _foo_internal_anon_3(d):
                def _foo_internal_anon_4(e):
                    return a + b + c + d + e
                return _foo_internal_anon_4
            return _foo_internal_anon_3
        return _foo_internal_anon_2
    return _foo_internal_anon_1
```